# Use authentication for more than one model in cakephp 3

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to have a web page with two kinds of logins, one for "**users**" and another one for "**handlers**". Both kind of models are very different from each other and, therefore, I can't make the login by giving them different roles.

What I want is to have two sepparate views where each kind of person can access the web and maintain their session open while they are logged in, but I don't know how to handle this in my `AppController` (when loading the `Auth` component).

I have tried using alliases and reconfiguring my Auth component in the controller where the second component should be used, but none of these options have worked in my case.

Comment: even if they are completely different (like users and admins are), there should be no reason not to share login
The point after the login is what matters - it can be a role based prefix for example to separate everything.
Users can be a separate additional table per role to hold additional "custom" info per role, e.g. Handlers in your case on top of the normal Users table data.

Comment: The thing is I have a data structure I can not modify, and therefore, I cant't assign roles, which is why I wanted to have two sepparate Auth components.